# Setting an array item's value as the parent array's key (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => I100
            [name] => Mary
            [gender] => F
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => I101
            [name] => John
            [gender] => M
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => I245
            [name] => Sarah
            [gender] => F
        )
)
```

I want to set the key of the parent array with the value of `id`, so the result array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [I100] => Array
        (
            [id] => I100
            [name] => Mary
            [gender] => F
        )
    [I101] => Array
        (
            [id] => I101
            [name] => John
            [gender] => M
        )
    [I245] => Array
        (
            [id] => I245
            [name] => Sarah
            [gender] => F
        )
)
```

If possible I'd like to avoid using an additional loop to go through the array and creating a new array to store each item with the proper key, as the array can have thousands of items.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: And what you have tried so far? From where did you were getting this array

Comment: The loop is unavoidable (it can be hidden with a built in function like `array_map` but its still there). Perhaps you can alter the code that generates the array in the 1st place? If not, then loop

Comment: Show the code where you made the first array.

Comment: The fastest way is using a loop and not a built in function.

Comment: The code that made the original array is irrelevant as it cannot be altered.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your caveat, a loop is the obvious solution:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($oldArray as $item)
    $newArray[$item['id']] = $item;
```

If the problem you have is not specifically with a loop, but rather creating a copy of the array is causes excessive memory consumption, then you can edit the array in place, with a for loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($oldArray); $i++){
    $oldArray[$oldArray[$i]['id']] = $oldArray[$i];
    unset($oldArray[$i]);
}
```

*Note this works because the `id` elements are alphanumeric strings, if they where simple integars then the above code could overwrite sections.*

The only other solution is to build the correct array in the 1st place, in a similar manner.

For example, using `PDO::fetch` instead of `PDO::fetchAll`:

```
//$newArray = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$newArray = [];
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $newArray[$row['id']] = $row;
```

Comment: The code that created the original array cannot be altered.

Comment: OK, well then you have to loop. I just made an edit to give a memory friendly option if thats your actual issue with looping. If thats not, then you need to clarify **why** you dont want to use a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can't overwrite keys while iterating through an array "on the fly". So here is solution with `array_map` which produces an array with needed structure:

```
// assuming $arr is your initial array
$result = [];

array_map(function($a) use (&$result){
    $result[$a['id']] = $a;
}, $arr);

// $result contains the needed array
```

Comment: Note this still creates a copy of the array, and is slower than a regular foreach loop, but as the OP has not specified **why** they dont want to use a loop, this is technically a reasonable answer

Comment: I also wish to know how someone is going to change all keys in initial array  on the fly without loop and creating new array

Answer (score 0):

You can add needed key during creation of this array.